# how to solve CordovaLib:processDebugResources error in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

**strong text**`enter code here`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.627 secs
Error: /home/saurabh/saurabh_workspace/ecard/mobile/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
```

Comment: ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android

Comment: This isn't working! Whatever I do this error keeps coming!

Answer (score -1):

How I solved this problem:

I found that SDK 4.1 was not installed in my system and Cordova required SDK 4.1+ So I have

1. Installed android 4.1 and 4.4 SDK in my **android studio.** Then
2. Created a dummy project in android studio and run that project in my device(mobile).

Once every thing is working fine in android studio then..

I have run the command `Cordova run android` in terminal..